# htaccess in php

Tags: php

I am using htaccess in my projec.there is login section i want to show the my account page as http:///www/domain.com/username . But there is a problem because i have also made a cms which is open as http:///www/domain.com/cms . 
                                        Although i have validate the user name But there is same page open when i open the cms or user profile page.
 I have pass the regular expression in htaccess  but stil not required result is come

Comment: Sorry, but I am not sure if I understand what you are trying to do.  Maybe you should post the content of your .htaccess file / what you tried so far in order to make things more clear?

Comment: i want to manage the all php file manage with htaccess and if user successfully login in my website i want to show my account page as baseurl/username like http://google.com/badshah but there is cms also i opened this in url as baseurl/cms like http://www.google.com/cms 
But in this url open my account page not cms i want to change this

Answer (score 1):

If http://www.domain.com is hosted in /path/to/site/ and http://www.domain.com/cms in /path/to/site/cms/ then this should work :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]*)$ %{SCRIPT_URL}index.php?username=$1
```